# Laravel 8 - read .env variables inside customized config file

Tags: php, laravel, environment-variables, laravel-8

I’m facing a curious situation. I’m in the middle of the process of replicating a framework that I developed in node / react to laravel. Right now, I’m adjusting the main architecture.

I have a customized configuration file where I store all my configuration variables so my framework can change it’s behavior for each project I develop.

Up till now, with the architecture I’ve set up, I’m able to access env variables in my .env in every part of my application with the env(‘SOME_CONSTANT’) method. And I’m able to access my configuration variables that I store in a centralized file with $GLOBALS[‘someVariable’] call.

The problem is that now, I’d like for a variable inside my config file to access a env variable. For some architectural reason, it’s not working (nor returning me the values stored in the .env file.

Right now, this is how my /public/index.php is set up to import the customized configuration variables:

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Check If Application Is Under Maintenance
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If the application is maintenance / demo mode via the "down" command we
| will require this file so that any prerendered template can be shown
| instead of starting the framework, which could cause an exception.
|
*/

if (file_exists(__DIR__.'/../storage/framework/maintenance.php')) {
    require __DIR__.'/../storage/framework/maintenance.php';
}

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| this application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so we don't need to manually load our classes.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
//require __DIR__.'/../php_modules/vendor/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request using
| the application's HTTP kernel. Then, we will send the response back
| to this client's browser, allowing them to enjoy our application.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

$kernel = $app->make(Kernel::class);

require __DIR__ . '/../config-application.php'; // Customized configuration.

$response = tap($kernel->handle(
    $request = Request::capture()
))->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

In my .env file, I have something like this:

```
CONFIG_DIRECTORY_FILES_LAYOUT_SD = "files-layout"
```

And in my customized configuration file, I have something like this:

```
$configDirectoryFilesLayoutSD = env('CONFIG_DIRECTORY_FILES_LAYOUT_SD');
```

Is there any way I could access the information I want from the .env file, either with the current setup or any other setup? I know that I could move everything over to /config directory, but that’s not my intention, since I want to maintain a certain similarity in architectural setup with my other frameworks.

Thanks, in advance!
Note: I’m new to Laravel, so the answer may be simple.

Comment: Did you already run `php artisan cache:clear`and `php artisan config:clear`?

Comment: Yes. In fact, I ran all clean up and rebuild sequence: composer dump-autoload,  composer dump-autoload -o, php artisan clear-compiled, php artisan optimize, php artisan route:clear, php artisan view:clear, php artisan cache:clear, php artisan config:cache, php artisan config:clear

Comment: I would not recommend to modify how Laravel works, because you are modifying core code and concepts the framework is very opinionated about, so it will be more difficult to upgrade (in the future) and also, if someone new starts working on this Laravel project, everything will be different instead of what that developer (and the community) knows about Laravel... This is not Symfony where you do whatever you want (hierarchy), so I would recommend you avoid doing modifications like that, it is going to be harder for you and someone else

Comment: I understand. The thing is that for this particular project, I doubt that it would be shared with teams to work in. Besides that, these "unconventional" necessities I´m having for transcribing this particular code base, gives me a chance to dive in the code for deeper understanding on Laravel framework as a whole. Just out of curiosity, where would you recommend I place configuration variables, outside .env file?

Comment: I would recommend to put them inside `/config` folder (inside a file) as Laravel does. Maybe you can place them in another part and not `config`, but I would still recommend to use the way Laravel uses (return an array with data as a config). You can have a look at how an `.env` is read, have a look [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/c6d1a2da17e3aaaeb0ff5b8cc4879816d214b527/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/LoadEnvironmentVariables.php#L20-L33)